# How to Paste into visible cells in a filter in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have data in one workbook and I have filtered columns in another workbook, when I want to copy the data from one workbook and paste it to the visible cells in the filtered area, it gets pasted to the hidden cells as well.

I googled alot but nothing was useful even I tried the Kutools software but did not work.

How to paste the data into visible cells?

Comment: it might be helpful to know what you use to filter the 2nd workbook (destination) on and whether this info is available in the first workbook (source) as well.

Comment: I filter the cells by color in the second workbook.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I like to use is to use reference in the filtered sheet. Slightly longer method, but it works. Follow the steps below

- Set the reference in first cell. E.g. `='Sheet1!A1'`
- Click and drag to copy the formula to all cells below (or Copy, and Paste into multiple selection). DO NOT double click to fill down, as it will include hidden cells.
- If needed, clear filter and copy- paste values

Let me know if this works for you.